# SQL: Subtracting from different tables and using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been trying to find an answer about this that solves my problem. I understand how to subtract from separate tables, but not in the context that I need it to work.

```
      SELECT I.IngredientName AS 'Ingredient Name', QOH AS 'Quantity On Hand',       
      SUM(BrewLine.Quantity) AS 'Total Ingredient Used'
      FROM INGREDIENT I
      INNER JOIN BrewLine 
      ON I.IngredientName = BrewLine.IngredientName 
      GROUP BY I.IngredientName, QOH
```

I need to have another field where I subtract QOH from SUM(BrewLine.Quantity) in order to have an, 'amount' remaining in the output. What is a way to go about this? If I just subtract them and then have to include them in GROUP BY. My output is all askew.

Thank you

Comment: Please include example data so that we can see what `all askew` actually means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the partitioning functions instead of the grouping functions, which I think is what you're trying to accomplish...

```
SELECT 
    I.IngredientName AS 'Ingredient Name', 
    QOH AS 'Quantity On Hand',    
    QOH - SUM(BrewLine.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY I.IngredientName) AS 'Amount'
FROM INGREDIENT I
INNER JOIN BrewLine 
      ON I.IngredientName = BrewLine.IngredientName
```